# React Native checkbox icon from "Tick" to "-"(hyphen)

Tags: react-native, checkbox, react-native-vector-icons

I am using react native checkBox from "@react-native-community/checkbox". I am able to use it correctly. But, my question is how can I change the tick icon inside the checkbox to hyphen inside the checkbox(indeterminate checkbox).

```
<CheckBox
   value={isSelected}
   onValueChange={setSelection}
   style={styles.checkbox}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make custom checkbox as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Image, View, SafeAreaView, Text} from 'react- 
native';
import {useState} from 'react';
import IconAntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

export function CheckBoxFinal() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          borderWidth: 2,
        }}
        onPress={() => setCount(!count)}>
        {count ? (
          <IconAntDesign name="minus" size={15} color={'black'} />
        ) : null}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```